# mvc renderpartial dialog difficulty

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I have a view in which I have the following code:

```
  <div id="DivPassword" > 
<%Html.RenderPartial("PasswordDetails"); %>
```

I want to display the div as a dialog, in which I am successful. When I click on a link the dialog opens.

However, I can see that the partial view is also being displayed in the View, when the page loads.  Why is it so?  How can I correct that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It displays because your code generates markup like:

```
<div id="DivPassword" ><!-- contents of partial view here --></div>
```

When a browser sees this markup, id displays stuff. :)

In order to not display the dialog *until* you run some JavaScript to make it display, you need to hide it. You can do this with a CSS rule:

```
div#DivPassword
{
     visibility: hidden;
}
```

Pretty much all JS dialog libraries will change the visibility when you pop up the dialog.